# Why does rxjs 6 marbles documentation say "--(abc)-|" completes on frame 8?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jasmine, jestjs, rxjs-marbles

I am reading over the marbles testing documentation for Rxjs 6, and found this part under the "Examples" section for "Marble Syntax"

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md#examples

Here is the example for my question:

> '--(abc)-|': on frame 2 emit a, b, and c, then on frame 8 complete

Why does it say frame 8 for complete?

I count only 5 frames in total for the above string. The string `(abc)` should only count as a single frame. It's then followed by another frame `-` then a complete `|`.

```
--(abc)-|
11  1  11 = sum(5)
```

So I don't understand why it's frame 8, but when I run the above in a unit test with marbles it outputs that it completed on frame 8.

So where are the 3 extra frames coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended because when the event is outside parentheses it calculates the frame only from its string position. I believe the main reason is that you can still put multiple marble diagram under each other and it's still easily readable:

```
combineLatest([
  hot('-a--b-----c-d-e-|'),
  hot('--------f--g-h-i--j-|'),
  hot('--1--(234)---5-6---|'),
]);
```

You can still easily tell when `5` is going to be emitted. If it worked as you expected then you'd have to manually subtract the frames to tell whether `5` goes before `d` and `g` for example.

It's not very obvious from the source code but it advances frames for every character in the diagram (the `advanceFrameBy(1)` call):

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L334

Comment: Okay, so that helped me fix a unit test, but I'm still a little confused about what the `-` character means, because I thought that was the passing of time? I was able to fix my unit test by padding values using `-` so that the frames aligned, but now I'm wondering what the `-` means.

Comment: Would `a---b` count as having 3 frames, because `---` is counted as a single frame?

Comment: `-` is just an empty space. It means that there're no events in that frame.

Comment: No, each `-` is one frame. Only `()` is special. There's also special "time progression" syntax but I'm not even sure this is documented anywhere. I haven't used that myself yet. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/schedulers/TestScheduler-spec.ts#L87

Comment: thank you! This really helped. My tests are passing now.