# Combine RxJS marble diagrams

Tags: rxjs, observable, marble-diagram

I'm testing an observable that might be described with following diagram:

```
-a(bcdef) // emit one value at first frame and 5 values in second frame
--g       // emit one value at third frame
```

But I cannot describe this observable in single diagram, which is expected by function **expectObservable().toBe**

When I write a diagram like below:

```
-a(bcdef)g
```

**g** appears to be in 9th frame, but I want the value to appear in the 3rd frame.

I also tried to use combineLatest to combine multiple diagrams into single one like below, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998667/why-does-rxjs-6-marbles-documentation-say-abc-completes-on-frame-8) suggestion

```
const values = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g };
const expected1$ = cold('-a(bcdef)', {a, b, c, d, e, f  });
const expected2$ = cold('--g', { g });

const expected$ = combineLatest([
  expected1$,
  expected2$
]);
```

but unfortunately I've got an error.

Please advice how to test this case with marbles and if it's even possible to combine expected marbles?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: You can find the error at the screenshot https://prnt.sc/20ydpni

The problem is that value of 'g' expected to be in time frame 3 but it comes after parantheses and appears in 9th frame, an when I include value of 'g' into parantheses it appears in frame 2. How to build the diagram to make  'g' be in frame 3?

Comment: Could you filter out everything __except for__ g? E.g. `source.pipe(filter(x => x !== 'g'))`. That way you could write `.toBe('---g', ... )` and then do it once again, but filtering for the other values